# Deserialize issue JsonProperty ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a custom property:

```
[JsonProperty("123abc")]
public int Id {get; set;}
```

and

```
var container = Serializer.Deserialize<ResponseContainer<T>>(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
```

It seems I have to override DefaultContractResolver, which is part of the code I inherited, which may not have actually handled a custom field.

```
private readonly Dictionary<MemberInfo, string> _names = new Dictionary<MemberInfo, string>();

public ContractResolver() : base(false) { }

protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
{  return propertyName;     }

protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
   var lst = new List<JsonProperty>();
   foreach (var member in GetSerializableMembers(type))     {
          var prop = CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
                    string customName;
          **if (_names.TryGetValue(member, out customName))
                 prop.PropertyName = customName;**
          lst.Add(prop);
    }
    return lst;
}
```

The "highlighted lines" don't do the "mapping," Id is always 0. I looked up some answers, and changed the code to:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings  = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"Id", "123abc"}  };   
protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    string resolvedName = null;
    var resolved = this.PropertyMappings.TryGetValue(propertyName, out resolvedName);
    return (resolved) ? resolvedName : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
}
```

It errors on converting null to int. I'm probably missing out on some fine detail... Please advice. Thanks!